# How to open http for linux server

Tags: linux, iptables, bash, redhat

I am a Windows (IIS) software engineer, but recently I've been thrown into a Linux server admin role until we can find someone to fill the position. I am not ashamed to admit I have no idea what I am doing.

Currently the problem I am trying to solve is that the server is only responding to https requests. However, **we need it to respond to standard http requests as well.**

We don't really have anything that needs to stay secure on its way to the requester.

I am running redhat linux with a bash shell.

If anyone could tell me how to enable http requests I would really appreciate it!

Please make sure your response is fairly step by step as I have minimal command line experience :/

Comment: `I am a Windows (IIS) software engineer, but recently I've been thrown into a Linux server admin role` -- Your username is perfect! LOL

Comment: check if ipv4 is listening to all ports. run command `netstat -lpt` and post output

Comment: Do you know if the box is running SELinux?

Comment: First, please clarify what "not responding" means. Is the connection refused, timing out, blank page, something else? Then you can begin to determine why it is happening.

Comment: Since you are running Red Hat I would suggest looking into the Red Hat knowledgebase if your subscription is still valid.  In addition you may have access to telephone support from Red Hat where you will speak to someone who knows Linux.

Comment: Connection refused

Comment: What distro? Assuming RHEL ensure that the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf has a Listen 80 directive.

Comment: When you say respond to standard http requests do you mean with the same content that is on https or with different content?

Comment: @lain same content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your system is RHEL 6 then

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

should open the port for you.

If your system is RHEL 5 then

```
iptables -I  RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

would be the normal way to do it.

Either way if once it's working then

```
service iptables-save
```

will save the current firewall state to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

Comment: completes successfully, but still does not connect when I try to access a page via http... maybe this is an app problem?

Comment: @wtcoder: what solved the problem - this doesn't seem like it did

Comment: it didn't; but I am convinced the problem is with the app at this point. Your command line worked for the question I asked... when I hit the site with http it just switches to https; it's when I hit the deeper pages that this problem occurs.

Comment: @wtcoder: Ah, right - you probably have some rewriting going on in one of your configuration files in `/etc/httpd...` take a look at http://serverfault.com/search?q=apache+rewrite+http+to+https to see what you're looking for

Comment: I don't think this is occuring in apache because it is not happening on all the pages, if it was it would do it for all pages and I would have no troubles :)
In asp.net I can do this:
`if (!Request.IsSecure) throw new ErrorException();`
I suspect something thign similar is happening in this app. My company bought a social engine running on linux thing and as the most technical person they just threw it in my lap hahaha Still have a lot to figure out

Answer (score 0):

Also, as a non-root user, you cannot listen on port 80. If you wish to have your services listen on port 80, you will have to relay traffic:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
$ sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Comment: You assume that the webserver is Apache.

Comment: The webserver is apache